# Automate Application Installation with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to write a powershell script that would install my team's web application and all the web application's dependencies (ie: telerik, asp.net mvc3, third-party assemblies) with a single click of a button. Is this possible? Or does someone have to click "Next" to go through an installation wizard?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for MSDeploy. This ships with PowerShell cmdlets (and a regular console executable.)

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

**Features**

- Seamless integration with IIS 7.0
  Manager and Visual Studio 2010
  interface for creating packages and
  deploying them onto a machine, both
  locally and remotely.
- Seamless integration with the Web
  Platform Installer to install
  community web applications simply and
  easily.

*Web application packaging:*

- Ability to package a Web application
  or an entire site, including the
  associated databases.
- Ability to package ACLs, COM, GAC and
  registry settings.
- Supports both live servers and zipped
  packages as a source or destination.

*Web application deployment:*

- Administrative privileges are not
  required in order to deploy Web
  applications.
- Ability to add powerful parameters to
  change text in files when they are
  deployed (such as prompting to
  replace a connection string when
  deploying from QA to staging
  environments).
- Integration with the IIS 7.0 Web
  Management Service (WMSVC) for remote
  deployment by non-administrators.
- Server administrators have granular
  control over the operations that can
  be performed and can delegate tasks
  to non-administrators.

*Web server migration and synchronization:*

- Ability to synchronize or migrate the
  entire Web server, a Web site or
  application.  Synchronizes only the
  data that has changed.
- Ability to detect missing
  dependencies during synchronization.
- Automatically gathers content, IIS
  configuration, SSL certificates and
  ASP.NET configuration when you sync a
  Web site.

In addition to the IIS Manager and Visual Studio 10, tasks can be performed using the command-line or public APIs.

-Oisn